# HDMI connection not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I've been trying to get a HDMI connection from my laptop to my TV. I realise there are a LOT of posts similar to this but none I've found have worked for me.
System specs are; Intel® Core™ i7-8750H CPU, GeForce GTX 1060, Ubuntu 18.04.

I have installed the latest Nvidia Driver(410), tried with the original driver(390) I installed and tried with Nouveau.

The output of xrandr is :

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 214mm
```

Then a long list of resolutions, no HDMI or VGA mentioned. I have tried this with the HDMI cable connected and disconnected.
I then found a question which pointed me here; https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HDMI

The output of get-edid | parse-edid looks more promising;

```
    This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
No EDID on bus 8
No EDID on bus 9
2 potential busses found: 7 10
Will scan through until the first EDID is found.
Pass a bus number as an option to this program to go only for that one.
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 7
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "PHILIPS FTV"
    ModelName "PHILIPS FTV"
    VendorName "PHL"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 20 of 2015
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 640 360
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "false"
    Horizsync 30-83
    VertRefresh 56-76
    # Maximum pixel clock is 170MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz

    #Extension block found. Parsing...
    Modeline    "Mode 16" 148.50 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 1" 84.75 1360 1432 1568 1776 768 771 776 798 -hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 2" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 3" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 4" 74.250 1920 2558 2602 2750 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 5" 74.250 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 6" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 7" 74.250 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1082 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 8" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1082 1087 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 9" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 10" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 11" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 12" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 13" 27.000 1440 1464 1590 1728 576 578 581 625 -hsync -vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 14" 27.027 1440 1478 1602 1716 480 484 487 525 -hsync -vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 15" 25.200 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 17" 74.25 1920 2558 2602 2750 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 18" 74.25 1920 2448 2492 2640 540 542 547 562 +hsync +vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 19" 74.25 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
    Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 16"
EndSection
```

The only problem is I have absolutely no idea what to do with this information. I could not find a xorg.conf file in any of the locations mentioned under `# man xorg.conf` so I opened Nvidia X Server and created one. My problem now is how should I edit this with the information I obtained from `get-edid | parse-edid`. Is this even worth trying or am I on the wrong route?? The contents of my xorg.conf is below. Thank you for taking the time to read this/help.

```
    # nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 415.27

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1060"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Virtual     1920 1080
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Creating the xorg.cof file caused the 'purple screen issue' after login. Had to boot from USB and `rm` it. Any takers yet??